# Use memory indexing into aws lambda? Circumvent stateless in lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I’m researching my options to publish microservices under AWS lambda. As we will be billed by the microsecond and memory used, performance of our lambda functions is pretty important.

4. **I have code that consult DB and load entire tables on indexes on memory for better performance in subsequent requests/filters/queries. Can I use this code into a lambda function? Some way to circumvent stateless in lambda ?**

Comment: You should really be using Redis for this instead of doing this in the same memory space as your Lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

1. you can run your code in a lambda and put the loaded entire table into elastiCache (Amazon ElastiCache offers fully managed Redis and Memcached.) which can be accessed by other lambdas for further queries.
2. you can even reuse your connections (connection pooling) as it cuts several milliseconds off your execution time.
3. Any variable outside the lambda_handler function will be frozen in
   between Lambda invocations and possibly reused. The documentation
   states to “not assume that AWS Lambda always reuses the container
   because AWS Lambda may choose not to reuse the container.” but it's
   observed that depending on the volume of executions, the container
   is almost always reused.

Comment: 1. is a total rewrite of my code and a not so performant solution. I use java HashTables , Maps and other data structures and indexes for fast search and data retrieval from memory, I don't want/need SQL for subsequent queries

Comment: 3. If I can't trust on the container vars reuse 100%, I can't trust at all, or I must code an alternative if not used. I suppose than on executing lambda on a new server is not used container, variables doesn't exists and I must code to go to DB on this case and fill the vars.